# How to visualize the relationship of tables in an Oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, visualization, entity-relationship

I know in Access there is a way I can visualize the relationship between tables in a diagram - kind of like an ER diagram.

I am new to Oracle. I am wondering if I can do the same/similar thing with Oracle. Could someone give some suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

[Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html) -  Tool recently launched by Oracle.

[Schemaspy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) is good if you require an offline easy to navigate html report.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle don't provide a tool for free.  Their [SQL Developer Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/datamodeler/index.html) is pretty good but price-y if you need to buy a commercial license.

If you are interested in platform independence then [Power Architect](http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect) is FOSS.

Comment: Thanks APC. Sadly, I only have Oracle Sql Developer.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer *does* include the Data Modeler now:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18464_01/doc.30/e15802/tut_data_modeling.htm

Answer (score 2):

Download Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC), which is usually [packaged with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html).  Follow the install instructions for the Oracle ODBC driver.  Add a System DSN (Start > Run > type *odbcad32* press ENTER).

No you can open an entity-relationship diagram through MS Access, MS Visio, Visual Studio, Enterprise Architect, or other ODBC-compliant data tools.

For example, in MS Access:  File > Open > Under "Files of type", select ODBC Databases.  This selection is at the bottom of the drop-down list.  Select "Database Tools" tab, then "Relationships" to view the Oracle table relationships.  Here is a [link to an article where Oracle provides documentation on how to visualize the relationships during a migration from Access](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12154/troubleshooting_access.htm).

In MS Visio, choose FILE > NEW > "Software and Database" > "Database Model Diagram".  Then select "Database" from the top menu, and "Reverse Engineer".  Select the ODBC connection.  If you get an error, hit escape.  Continue until the diagram is loaded.

Enterprise Architect and Visual Studio offer much better capabilities, having similar instructions.

Hope that is clear and helpful.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: Please choose an answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt tool, but you can use some free ware, or even buy some of these if you really like them.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674911/light-weight-er-diagram-tool

[Good tool to visualise database schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433071/good-tool-to-visualise-database-schema)

My personal favorite is [ER/Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio)

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Sql Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/sql_developer/index.html) is free and have Query builder which can display diagram. You can drag and drop tables from list of tables in schema.

Comment: Thanks zendar, but I mean show the relationship between tables. Sorry if I am a little vague about this.

Comment: SQL Developer Modeler can do it, but it costs. SQL Developer (not Modeler) is free tool that can show diagram. It works like visual query builder in Ms Access. It does not have functionality like relationship diagram in Ms Access. You can download both and try them.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Access to Oracle via ODBC. Then display the oracle tables in access.

Comment: Manually drawing! What if you don't know but want the database management software to tell you?! (Ah. MS SQL Server is so good...)