# Is there a way to reverse engineer sql table creation scripts?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, reverse-engineering

I have exported my sql statements from phpmyadmin 'data.sql'. I wish to reverse engineer the sql file to display the relational database diagram. Is there a way? I tried tools such as Visio, it is not accepting .sql files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just executing it locally, and then look at all the tables, views, data, etc from there? All depends on what data.sql actually contains.  If its insert statements only, you can only guess on the schema.  If it is CREATE TABLE statements, you will have more luck.

Comment: executing it locally means? It contains the create table statements.

Comment: install an instance of MySQL on your laptop/PC at home. and actually run that SQL script against it.

Comment: But I want to reverse engineer the scripts to a database diagram visually.

Comment: Exact question asked before (and answered well) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433071/good-tool-to-visualise-database-schema

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple, although you won't get datatypes.  The data.sql should show you column names and table names, from there it's a pretty simple jump to assembling the table.

Answer (score 0):

That's not reverse engineering but you can certainly use tools such as [MySql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-home.html) to create ER Diagrams from existing databases.

For SQL Server, SSMS has an option to generate Database diagrams.