# visualize sqlite database schemaspy

Tags: java, sqlite, graph, schema

I am tring to visualize sqlite database. There are several pages discussing this but none of those solution worked for me [Good tool to visualize database schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433071/good-tool-to-visualise-database-schema) or [easy visualisation using sqlfairy](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/easy-visualisation-of-database-schemas-using-sqlfairy/) or [SchemaDisplay](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/SchemaDisplay). Seems that the problem is with SQLite.JDBCDriver. Here is discussion about [java and sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233/java-and-sqlite?rq=1) but i cannot figure it out. What I have done is renaming sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar to sqlite.jar hoping that helped but as you can see bad luck.

```
[pista@HP-PC schemaspy]$ ls -l
total 7084
drwxrwxr-x  3 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:34 javasqlite
drwxrwxr-x  2 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:05 lib
drwxrwxr-x 14 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:15 mendeley
drwxrwxr-x  2 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:13 out
drwxrwxr-x  2 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:05 properties
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista    2655 Feb 22  2009 README.TXT
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista  248945 Aug 16  2010 schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista  161441 Dec 12 22:04 schemaSpyGUI20090302.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista      26 Nov  4  2007 schemaSpyGUI.bat
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista  102299 Mar  2  2009 schemaSpyGUI.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista      86 Nov 18  2007 schemaSpyGUI.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista  284954 Dec 12 22:25 sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3070701.zip
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista 3201128 Dec 12 22:28 sqlite.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 pista pista 3201128 Aug 27  2010 sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
drwxrwxr-x  3 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:05 src
drwxrwxr-x  2 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:31 xerial
drwxrwxr-x  7 pista pista    4096 Dec 12 22:31 xerial-sqlite-jdbc-e0fd4e05a97e
[pista@HP-PC schemaspy]$ java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t sqlite -u pista -o out/ -db mendeley/wakatana@gmail.com@www.mendeley.com.sqlite 
Using database properties:
  [schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/sqlite.properties
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SQLite.JDBCDriver

Failed to load driver 'SQLite.JDBCDriver'from: [file:/home/pista/schemaspy/sqlite.jar]

Use the -dp option to specify the location of the database
drivers for your database (usually in a .jar or .zip/.Z).
```

What I am doing wrong, is this good approach ?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get sqlite to work with the schemaspy command line tool.  I used the sqlite jdbc driver from:

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

My sqlite.properties file looks like:

```
description=SQLite
connectionSpec=jdbc:sqlite:<db>
db=database name
driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
#you may need to put the full path to the driver depending on your setup
driverPath=sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-M1.jar
selectTablesSql=.tables
```

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC driver class is org.sqlite.JDBC, not SQLite.JDBCDriver.

I would suggest that you try [SchemaCrawler for SQLite](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/bundled.html), which is a free and open-source database documentation tool. The SchemaCrawler for SQLite download comes bundled with a later version of the SQLite JDBC driver, 3.7.8, and no additional renaming of jars is needed.

Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler